# What graphics card will fit my pc

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, fit-pc

I am using ECS G41T-m16 motherboard which have bus speed of FSB 1333 mhz. I have been using 2gb ddr3 apacer ram 300mhz with intel duel core for last 2 years.Recently I want to buy a graphics card so what will fit my configuration?

Comment: PCI Express x16 - after that, anything that will fit in the box & not swamp your power supply.

Comment: How many watts is your power supply and how big is your case?  FYI:  High-end video cards will make the pci-e 1x slot unusable, as they are double wide.